# How to set a inline form to occupy 100% width under the navbar brand in "navbar"

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: This is how it is coming right now, notice the black gap, plus the navbar-brand and navbar form seem to be coliding]I am pretty new to bootstrap. I am trying to have an inline form in the navbar beside the navbar-brand. While re-sizing(responsiveness) the window, the form is coming below the navbar-brand link, but it is not coming 100% and hence looking awkward. Could anybody tell me where i am going wrong. Here's the full html code,
[image: This is how i want, on resizing, no gap should come, plus the navbar brand should not overlap the form.]
        
    
      
        
        
        
        Bootstrap 101 Template

```
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"><!--style = "background-image: url('Images/logo.png'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: repeat;"-->
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "navbar-header col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left" style = "background-color: red; height: 100%;">
                 <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">JanaSena Party</a>
                 <button class = "navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">JSP</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse col-lg-8 col-xs-12 pull-right" style = "background-color: green;">
                <form class="navbar-form" role = "form" style = "margin: 0; width: 100%; background-color: blue;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/129779

**CSS** :

```
.navbar-header{
   float:none;    
  }

  .navHeaderCollapse{
     width:100%;      
    }
```

**HTML** :

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"><!--style = "background-image: url('Images/logo.png'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: repeat;"-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; height: 100%;">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JanaSena Party</a>
                 <button class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">JSP</button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse col-lg-8 col-xs-12" style="background-color: green;">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="form" style="margin: 0; width: 100%; background-color: blue;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE** :

**bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/129807

**css** :

```
@media screen and (max-width:992px){

.navbar-header{
   float:none; 

  }

  .navHeaderCollapse{
     width:100%;
    float:left;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually, the form is now overlapping the brand, plus i want the form below the navbar-brand, only in medium to xtra-small, in large i want it to be beside the brand.

Comment: I've seen the updates and it still doesn't meet my requirements. I've updated my question with images so it is more clear. Can you please take a look at it. Thanks.